# exit status 56 when calling a child process

Tags: c, fork

I'm trying to call a program and get its return value. I use `fork()` and `execv()` to call the child process, and now waiting for a status, but I receive `56` as the exit status, and I don't understand why. I've checked the child process separately, and it works just fine.

What does 56 mean and how can I fix it?

---

This is a part the relevant code:

```
pid_t pid = fork(); 

if (pid < 0)                
    // handle error 

if (pid == 0) 
    execv(filename, argv);  // calls child process 

waitpid(pid, &status, 0); 

if (WIFEXITED(status))      
    // handle success 
else if(WIFSIGNALED(status)) 
    printf("%d\n", (int) WTERMSIG(status)); // here I get 56 now, when I print the error using stderror I get this: "Invalid request code"
```

Comment: Please show some relevant code.

Comment: That is incredibly vague, programs output differing exit codes. Try googling the program you're executing in your child process and see if it has a listing for exit codes.

Comment: Have you considered using errno?

Comment: First and foremost, on success `execve()` doesn't return and if error is encountered it returns `-1` and `errno` is set accordingly. What you are getting probably isn't from `fork()` nor `execve()`.

Comment: this is a part the relevant code:

pid_t pid = fork();
if(pid < 0) // handle error
if (pid == 0)
     execv(filename, argv); // calls child process
waitpid(pid, &status,0);
if (WIFEXITED(status)) // handle success
else if(WIFSIGNALED(status))
     printf("%d\n", (int)WTERMSIG(status)); // here I get 56

now, when I print the error using stderror I get this: "Invalid request code"

Answer (score 2):

You are not printing the exit status, but the number of signal that terminated the process. When the child process exits normally (WIFEXITED), you're not printing anything.
It should be like this:

```
if (WIFEXITED(status))      
    printf("%d\n", (int)WEXITSTATUS(status));
```